# What's the best type of Movement/collision detection for high-Speed games?

Tags: 2d, libgdx, collision-detection, platformer, collision-prediction

Before I begin I'd just like to make it clear that I am not familiar with many programming/development terms, so if anyone can link articles to any terms used it would greatly help things move along:

I'm currently working on a game that plays similar to Sonic Mania. Obviously, when the player is moving they can reach really high speeds, but this brings up a problem with my collision detection.

What's essentially happening on the backend is that the player is moving too fast to collide with the enemy; With the way I have my movement set up, (Essentially Player.xposition += Player.xvelocity) the player "Teleports" Through the enemy instead of hitting it. I tried the workaround shown below to get this working, but so far it only works if I'm willing to mele enemies from 50ft away:

```
    public boolean touches(Entity e) {
        float ex = e.pos.x; 
        float ey = e.pos.y; 
        float ewidth = e.getWidth();
        float eheight = e.getHeight();
        float tx = this.pos.x;
        float ty = this.pos.y;
        Boolean xtouches= false, ytouches = false;


        for(int i = 0; i<= this.getXvel(); i++) {
//runs through all numbers up to the velocity of the player to see if they will collide in this frame
        if(ex > tx) {
            if (ex+ewidth <= (tx+i) -this.getWidth()) { 
                xtouches = true;
                break;
            }else xtouches = false;
        }else if (ex < tx) {
            if (ex-ewidth >= (tx+i) +this.getWidth()){ 
                xtouches = true;
                break;
            }else xtouches = false;
        }else xtouches = true;
    }
        for(int i = 0; i<= this.getYvel(); i++) {
        if(ey > ty) {
            if (ey+eheight <= (ty+i) -this.getHeight()) {
                ytouches = true;
                break;
            }
            else ytouches = false;
        }else if (ey < ty) {
            if (ey-eheight >= (ty+i) +this.getHeight()){
                ytouches = true;
                break;
            }
            else ytouches = false;
        }else ytouches = true;
        }
        return (xtouches && ytouches);
    }
```

I've tried looking up different algorithms for hit detection online, but what I found is the same as what I have (without the for loops), and I don't know how else to change my movement methods without changing core mechanics in ways I don't want.
Is there a way to change either my hit registration or style of movement to prevent this problem?

Comment: This is usually solved by sub-stepping or continuous collision detection. How have you tried applying those approaches to your case?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm pretty sure that the method I have in the question is some form of CCD (Although these terms are all very new to me so I could be wrong; I'll update the question to reflect that). I also haven't heard of sub-stepping, do you know of any good sources on it?

Comment: No, what you've shown is not CCD. It's more similar to sub-stepping, where you test multiple points along the trajectory, but splitting it into two loops separated by axis means you can get some weird behaviour on diagonals.